# ArrayList java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting stumped by this error.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
```

Below is the code that is causing the exception.  'keys' is an ArrayList.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        if (values[i] != null) {
            contentValues.put(keys.get(i), String.valueOf(values[i]));
        }
    }
```

What could be causing this outOfBoundsException?

Comment: What line is this error on?

Comment: You aren't bounds-checking your access to `values`.

Comment: Your value array is 10 elements long, starting with 0 and going to 9. It looks like `keys` is eleven elements long - that's why you'd end up with `i == 10`. Where do you define keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is pretty self explanatory. The index you try to access does not exist. Java uses zero based indexing. Which means that if you have something of size `10`, it's indices are `0-9`

In your `for` loop you never check if `values[i]` can go up to `10`; Which apparently can't.

By the looks of it, `values[]` is of size `10` and `keys` is bigger.

Comment: Thank you.  I can't believe I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the error is on the `if` statement.  How do you knows that `values[i]` exists?  You're not iterating on `values`, you're iterating on `keys`.

But, you haven't given us enough information to know for sure.  What line does this occur on?